# Facebook Invite Friends Box with iframes

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'd like the Invite Friends Box on the bottom of my Landing Page in facebook. It worked with the old fbml but with iframes it doesn't show up. Here is the Code:

```
<div style="padding: 0px;"> <fb:request-form method="get" action="index.php" content="Fan" <fb:req-choice url='http://www.facebook.com/xyz' label='YES' />" type="page" invite="true" rows="3"> <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"> <fb:multi-friend-selector condensed="false" style="width:520px;" showborder="black" actiontext="Invite your friends" rows="3" cols="3"/> </div> </fb:request-form> </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: and when it shows up its not usable, the confirm dialog will be out of visible area. you can use requests 2.0 for it, the selector dialog is displayed above the page (not the iframe itself) see http://www.facebook.com/ManhattanFitness?sk=app_175200199201756 for an example

Comment: As serious developers, It is solely **our** responsibility to keep upto date with regard to changes that are happening with the 3rd party API (facebook platform) that we use.  You should keep an eye on the [Facebook Developers Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and also the [Developers Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).  Any changes will be detailed there and also **alternatives for deprecated methods.**

Answer (score 2):

If you want FB invite friend in an iFrame you have to initiate the facebook Connect API first and for this we need XFBML initialization in the bottom of the page.

You should use `fb:serverfbml` tag to get fb:friend-selector working.

Here is the iFrame body

```
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 650px;"> 
<script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml> 
        <fb:request-form
            action="http://your-site.com/invite/sent"
            method="POST"
            invite="true"
            type="My App"
            content="Try out my app!
                <fb:req-choice url='http://your-facebook-canvas-url'
                label='<?php echo htmlspecialchars("Accept button text",ENT_QUOTES); ?>'
                /> 
            " > 
            <fb:multi-friend-selector
                showborder="false"
                actiontext="Invite your friends."
                exclude_ids="If any excluded Ids will goes here"
                rows="3"
            /> 
        </fb:request-form> 
    </fb:fbml>
</script> 
</fb:serverfbml>
```

The above script will display the invite friend iFrame.

Here is the FB.connect code

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(
        ["CanvasUtil"],
        function(){
             FB.XdComm.Server.init('/xd_receiver.html');
             FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
        }
    );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ FB.Facebook.init("Your Facebook API Key", "/xd_receiver.html"); });   
</script>
```